# How to delete all files except directories?

Tags: bash, directory, delete-file, subdirectory

I was searching unsuccessfully for a solution to delete all the files inside a working directory except for the subdirectories inside.

I found a way to delete all the files inside all the directories, but I'm looking for a way to delete only the files on the same "level" I'm on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

The `find` command recursively searches a directory for files and folders that match the specified expressions.

- `-maxdepth 1` will only search the current level (when used with `.` or the top level when a directory is used instead), effectively turning of the recursive search feature
- `-type f` specifies only files, and all files

@[chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) recommended an improvement on the above to simply use

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -delete
```

Not sure why I didn't think of it in the first place but anyway.

Comment: If `-print0` is available, most likely so is `-delete`.

Comment: This is great and versatile, though I receive the following output: find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

rm: missing operand
Try `rm --help' for more information.
All the files in the folder were deleted

Comment: just switch around arguments, `find` wants `-maxdepth`... well, second actually, before `-type`

Comment: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -delete` >> Works perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I think it is as easy as this:

```
$ rm *
```

when inside the working directory.

I've tested it and it worked - it deleted all files in the working directory and didn't affected any files inside any subdirectory.

Keep in mind, that it if you want to remove hidden files as well, then you need:

```
$ rm * .*
```

Comment: @IKavanagh, but it still successfully deletes all the files. Thanks for pointing it out anyway!

Comment: How would you know if the files were successfully deleted though, in say a script?

Comment: @IKavanagh, you are absolutely right. Your answer is a lot better than mine. For everyday use I'd go for `rm *` however.

Comment: Thank you, it works great except the error message on the folder - but it does the job.